# Jquery ajax get specific div from string without parsing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
// Ajax Response data
<div class="body">
  <div class="product-essential">
       // Data needed
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     // Some javascript code executing
  </script>
</div>   


 jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: reqUrl,
    success: function (data) {
            var productData = jQuery(data).find('.product-essential');
    }
});
```

Here I am calling a page by ajax and getting the `.product-essential` element.

But when I wrap `data` in `jquery(data)` it also parses the script tags in the `response data` string which is creating problem.

Is there any way to get the element without parsing the scripts.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Show your code through an online editor, please.

Comment: "But jquery(data) also parses every script tags on the page which is creating problem" what problem is it creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a regular expression - https://regex101.com/r/Rg0TLN/1

```
var productData = jQuery(data.replace(/(<script.*?)(<\/script>)/gs, "")).find('.product-essential');
```